# How to create a Notification?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm new to programming and making an inventory system in  Android Studio and I just wanna know how to create a notification  that will show whenever an item is running lo, it is empty or it is expired.

here is the adding class where the user can add the items:
`public class AddItems extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    String userID;
    DatabaseHelp db;

    TextView textViewHeader;
    Button buttonBack, buttonAdd, buttonClear;
    EditText editTextProductName, editTextCategory, editTextPrice, editTextQuantity, editTextExpiration;

    AlertDialog alertDialogDeleteItem;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        goBack();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_items);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivityModule.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            userID = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        }

        db = new DatabaseHelp(this);

        textViewHeader = findViewById(R.id.addItem_textView_header);
        buttonBack = findViewById(R.id.addItem_button_back);
        buttonBack.setOnClickListener(v -> goBack());
        editTextProductName = findViewById(R.id.addItem_editText_productName);
        editTextCategory = findViewById(R.id.addItem_editText_category);
        editTextPrice = findViewById(R.id.addItem_editText_price);
        editTextQuantity = findViewById(R.id.addItem_editText_quantity);
        editTextExpiration = findViewById(R.id.addItem_editText_expiration);
        buttonAdd = findViewById(R.id.addItem_button_add);
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(v -> addItem());
        buttonClear = findViewById(R.id.addItem_button_clear);
        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (InventoryBills.isEditing) {
                alertDialogDeleteItem.show();
            } else {
                clearFields();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderDeleteItem = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilderDeleteItem.setCancelable(true);
        alertDialogBuilderDeleteItem.setTitle("Warning");
        alertDialogBuilderDeleteItem.setMessage(R.string.deleteItem_warning);
        alertDialogBuilderDeleteItem.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, which) -> deleteItem());
        alertDialogBuilderDeleteItem.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, (dialog, which) -> alertDialogDeleteItem.dismiss());
        alertDialogDeleteItem = alertDialogBuilderDeleteItem.create();

        if (InventoryBills.isEditing) {
            textViewHeader.setText(R.string.addItem_textView_editHeader);

            ProductItem item = InventoryBills.selectedItem;

            editTextProductName.setText(item.getProductName());
            editTextCategory.setText(item.getCategory());
            editTextPrice.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));
            editTextQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQuantity()));
            editTextExpiration.setText(item.getExpiration());

            buttonAdd.setText(R.string.addItem_button_addToEdit);
            buttonClear.setText(R.string.addItem_button_clearToDelete);
        }
    }

    void goBack() {
        finish();
    }

    void addItem() {
        String productName = editTextProductName.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String category = editTextCategory.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String price = editTextPrice.getText().toString();
        String quantity = editTextQuantity.getText().toString();
        String expiration = editTextExpiration.getText().toString();

        boolean isProductNameValid = false;
        boolean isCategoryValid = false;
        boolean isPriceValid = false;
        boolean isQuantityValid = false;
        boolean isExpirationValid = false;

        if (productName.isEmpty()) {
            editTextProductName.setError("Product name is required");
        } else {
            isProductNameValid = true;
        }

        if (category.isEmpty()) {
            editTextCategory.setError("Category is required");
        } else {
            isCategoryValid = true;
        }

        if (price.isEmpty()) {
            editTextPrice.setError("Price is required");
        } else {
            isPriceValid = true;
        }

        if (quantity.isEmpty()) {
            editTextQuantity.setError("Quantity is required");
        } else {
            isQuantityValid = true;
        }

        if (expiration.isEmpty() || expiration.matches(InventoryBills.datePattern)) {
            isExpirationValid = true;
        } else {
            editTextExpiration.setError("Expiration date is not valid");
        }

        if (isProductNameValid && isCategoryValid && isPriceValid && isQuantityValid && isExpirationValid) {
            ProductItem item = db.checkIfItemExist(userID, productName, category);
            BigDecimal bdPrice = new BigDecimal(price);
            BigDecimal bdQuantity = new BigDecimal(quantity);

            if (InventoryBills.isEditing) {
                if (item.getId() > -1 && item.getId() != InventoryBills.selectedItem.getId()) {
                    if (db.editItem(item.getId(), productName, category, item.getPrice(), item.getQuantity().add(bdQuantity), expiration)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Item exist, quantity merged successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        db.deleteItem(InventoryBills.selectedItem.getId());
                        goBack();
                    }
                } else if (db.editItem(InventoryBills.selectedItem.getId(), productName, category, bdPrice, bdQuantity, expiration)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Item edited successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    goBack();
                }
            } else {
                if (item.getId() > -1) {
                    if (db.editItem(item.getId(), productName, category, item.getPrice(), item.getQuantity().add(bdQuantity), expiration)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Item exist, quantity merged successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else if (db.getTotalItems(userID) >= 700) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Maximum number of items in inventory reached (700 items)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (db.addItem(userID, productName, category, bdPrice, bdQuantity, expiration)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Item added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void clearFields() {
        editTextProductName.setText("");
        editTextCategory.setText("");
        editTextPrice.setText("");
        editTextQuantity.setText("");
        editTextExpiration.setText("");
    }

    void deleteItem() {
        boolean isDeleted = db.deleteItem(InventoryBills.selectedItem.getId());

        if (isDeleted) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item deleted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            goBack();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item failed to delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

`

and here is my database code for it:

```
enter public class DatabaseHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "JnsData.db";
    public DatabaseHelp (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table inventory (id integer primary key autoincrement, username text, product_name text, category text, price numeric, quantity numeric, timestamp datetime default current_timestamp, expiration date)");
        db.execSQL("create table cart (id integer primary key autoincrement, username text, product_name text, category text, price numeric, quantity numeric, timestamp datetime default current_timestamp, expiration date)");

        db.execSQL("create table transaction_ids (id integer primary key autoincrement, username text, timestamp datetime default current_timestamp)");
        db.execSQL("begin transaction");
        db.execSQL("update sqlite_sequence set seq = 1000000 where name = 'transaction_ids'");
        db.execSQL("insert into sqlite_sequence (name, seq) select 'transaction_ids', 1000000 where not exists (select changes() as change from sqlite_sequence where change <> 0)");
        db.execSQL("commit");

        db.execSQL("create table transactions (id integer primary key autoincrement, transaction_id numeric, product_name text, category text, price numeric, quantity numeric, expiration date)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists inventory");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists cart");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists transaction_ids");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists transactions");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public ProductItem checkIfItemExist(String username, String productName, String category) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("select * from inventory where username = '%s' and product_name = '%s' and category = '%s'", username, productName, category);

        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        ProductItem item = new ProductItem();

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            cur.moveToFirst();

            item.setId(cur.getInt(0));
            item.setUsername(cur.getString(1));
            item.setProductName(cur.getString(2));
            item.setCategory(cur.getString(3));
            item.setPrice(new BigDecimal(cur.getString(4)));
            item.setQuantity(new BigDecimal(cur.getString(5)));
            item.setTimestamp(cur.getString(6));
            item.setExpiration(cur.getString(7));
        }

        cur.close();
        return item;
    }

    public ProductItem checkIfItemExistInCart(String username, String productName, String category) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("select * from cart where username = '%s' and product_name = '%s' and category = '%s'", username, productName, category);

        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        ProductItem item = new ProductItem();

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            cur.moveToFirst();

            item.setId(cur.getInt(0));
            item.setUsername(cur.getString(1));
            item.setProductName(cur.getString(2));
            item.setCategory(cur.getString(3));
            item.setPrice(new BigDecimal(cur.getString(4)));
            item.setQuantity(new BigDecimal(cur.getString(5)));
            item.setTimestamp(cur.getString(6));
            item.setExpiration(cur.getString(7));
        }

        cur.close();
        return item;
    }

    public Cursor getItem(String username, String keyword) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query;

        if (keyword.isEmpty()) {
            query = String.format("select * from inventory where username = '%s'", username);
        } else {
            query = String.format("select * from inventory where username = '%s' and " +
                            "(product_name like '%s%%' or category like '%s%%' or price like '%s%%' or quantity like '%s%%' or timestamp like '%s%%' or expiration like '%s%%')",
                    username, keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword);
        }

        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }

    public Cursor getItemInCart(String username, String keyword) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query;

        if (keyword.isEmpty()) {
            query = String.format("select * from cart where username = '%s'", username);
        } else {
            query = String.format("select * from cart where username = '%s' and " +
                            "(product_name like '%s%%' or category like '%s%%' or price like '%s%%' or quantity like '%s%%' or timestamp like '%s%%' or expiration like '%s%%')",
                    username, keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword);
        }

        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }

    public ArrayList<CartItems> getAllItemsInCart(String username) {
        ArrayList<CartItems> cart = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("select * from cart where username = '%s'", username);
        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cur.getCount() == 0) {
            return cart;
        }

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            cart.add(new CartItems(cur.getString(2), new BigDecimal(cur.getString(4)), new BigDecimal(cur.getString(5))));
        }

        cur.close();
        return cart;
    }

    public Cursor getItemByCategory(String username, String category) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("select * from inventory where username = '%s' group by %s", username, category);

        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }

    public Cursor getExpiredItem(String username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("select * from inventory where username = '%s' and expiration <= date() and expiration is not '' group by expiration", username);

        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }

    public int getTotalItems(String username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("select count(id) from inventory where username = '%s'", username);

        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int count = 0;

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            cur.moveToFirst();

            count = cur.getInt(0);
        }

        cur.close();
        return count;
    }

    public boolean addItem(String username, String productName, String category, BigDecimal price, BigDecimal quantity, String expiration) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("username", username);
        cv.put("product_name", productName);
        cv.put("category", category);
        cv.put("price", price.toPlainString());
        cv.put("quantity", quantity.toPlainString());
        cv.put("expiration", expiration);

        long result = db.insert("inventory", null, cv);
        return result != -1;
    }

    public boolean addItemInCart(String username, String productName, String category, BigDecimal price, BigDecimal quantity, String expiration) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("username", username);
        cv.put("product_name", productName);
        cv.put("category", category);
        cv.put("price", price.toPlainString());
        cv.put("quantity", quantity.toPlainString());
        cv.put("expiration", expiration);

        long result = db.insert("cart", null, cv);
        return result != -1;
    }

    public boolean editItem(int id, String productName, String category, BigDecimal price, BigDecimal quantity, String expiration) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("product_name", productName);
        contentValues.put("category", category);
        contentValues.put("price", price.toPlainString());
        contentValues.put("quantity", quantity.toPlainString());
        contentValues.put("expiration", expiration);
        return db.update("inventory", contentValues, "id = " + id, null) > 0;
    }

    public boolean editItemInCart(int id, String productName, String category, BigDecimal price, BigDecimal quantity, String expiration) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("product_name", productName);
        contentValues.put("category", category);
        contentValues.put("price", price.toPlainString());
        contentValues.put("quantity", quantity.toPlainString());
        contentValues.put("expiration", expiration);
        return db.update("cart", contentValues, "id = " + id, null) > 0;
    }

    public boolean deleteItem(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("inventory", "id = " + id, null) > 0;
    }

    public void deleteItemInCart(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("cart", "id = " + id, null);
    }

    public void deleteItemInCartOfUser(String username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("cart", "username = '" + username + "'", null);
    }

    public boolean insertTransactionID(String username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("username", username);

        long result = db.insert("transaction_ids", null, cv);
        return result != -1;
    }

    public int getCurrentTransactionID() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "select seq from sqlite_sequence where name = 'transaction_ids'";

        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int currentID = -1;

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            cur.moveToFirst();

            currentID = cur.getInt(0);
        }

        cur.close();
        return currentID;
    }

    public void addItemInTransactions(int transactionID, String productName, String category, BigDecimal price, BigDecimal quantity, String expiration) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("transaction_id", transactionID);
        cv.put("product_name", productName);
        cv.put("category", category);
        cv.put("price", price.toPlainString());
        cv.put("quantity", quantity.toPlainString());
        cv.put("expiration", expiration);

        db.insert("transactions", null, cv);
    }

    public boolean saveTransaction(ArrayList<TransacItems> transactionItems, String username) {
        if (insertTransactionID(username)) {
            int transactionID = getCurrentTransactionID();

            for (TransacItems item : transactionItems) {
                addItemInTransactions(transactionID, item.getProductName(), item.getCategory(), item.getPrice(), item.getQuantity(), item.getExpiration());
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public Cursor getTransactionItem(String username, String keyword) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query;

        if (keyword.isEmpty()) {
            query = String.format(
                    "select b.transaction_id, a.timestamp, b.product_name, b.category, b.price, b.quantity, b.expiration " +
                            "from transaction_ids a " +
                            "inner join transactions b on b.transaction_id = a.id " +
                            "where a.username = '%s'",
                    username);
        } else {
            query = String.format(
                    "select b.transaction_id, a.timestamp, b.product_name, b.category, b.price, b.quantity, b.expiration " +
                            "from transaction_ids a " +
                            "inner join transactions b on b.transaction_id = a.id " +
                            "where a.username = '%s' and " +
                            "(b.transaction_id like '%s%%' or a.timestamp like '%s%%' or b.product_name like '%s%%' or " +
                            "b.category like '%s%%' or b.price like '%s%%' or b.quantity like '%s%%' or b.expiration like '%s%%')",
                    username, keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword, keyword);
        }

        return db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }

    public BigDecimal[] getSalesStats(String username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = String.format(
                "select sum(b.price * b.quantity), sum(b.quantity) " +
                        "from transaction_ids a " +
                        "inner join transactions b on b.transaction_id = a.id " +
                        "where a.username = '%s'", username);

        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        BigDecimal v1 = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        BigDecimal v2 = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            cur.moveToFirst();

            String s1 = cur.getString(0);
            String s2 = cur.getString(1);

            if (s1 != null) {
                v1 = new BigDecimal(s1);
            }

            if (s2 != null) {
                v2 = new BigDecimal(s2);
            }
        }

        cur.close();
        return new BigDecimal[]{v1, v2};
    }

    public BigDecimal[] getInventoryStats(String username) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("select sum(price * quantity), sum(quantity) from inventory where username = '%s'", username);

        Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        BigDecimal v1 = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        BigDecimal v2 = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            cur.moveToFirst();

            String s1 = cur.getString(0);
            String s2 = cur.getString(1);

            if (s1 != null) {
                v1 = new BigDecimal(s1);
            }

            if (s2 != null) {
                v2 = new BigDecimal(s2);
            }
        }

        cur.close();
        return new BigDecimal[]{v1, v2};
    }
```

}
hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Make a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) that periodically runs in the background to check your database and launches a [Notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications) when your inventory is low or expired.